# Getting error while using JWPlayer6 in an iPad application

Tags: html, ipad, cordova, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have developed one hybrid application using Phonegap. In application we have pages for video category and video list. From video list, we navigate to a page which display a video file using jwplayer. This page works if we use jwplayer v5.0 but if we change syntax to jwplayer 6.0, application got crashed. Below is the error:

[image]

If I have also tried to run my page as index.html and in that file itself if I run below code then it works fine. But if from my list view page I navigate to this page then only it is causing problem. Here code available in videoPlayer.html page

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='myElement'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "video.mp4",
        image: "preview.jpg"
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please guide us, where could be the error for this?

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running the player in the html page?

Comment: Its local html plages, which we are embedding to iOS Phonegap application.

Comment: Does the issue happen if you just test locally, or only when running inside of Phonegap?

Comment: When running inside phonegap, that too only even when I navigate from other page. If I use this page as index page in phonegap, then it is running fine. I found its strange, what could be the reason?

Comment: I've never used PhoneGap before, so I can't really say why this would happen. We only officially test the player inside of the browser only, not inside of PhoneGap.